# Test to measure the significane of performance enhancement

Tags: statistical-significance

I have 5 different computational tasks. I executed both tasks on two laptops named LA and LB. Out of 5 tasks, 4 tasks were computed in less time on LB, while 1 task took less time on LA. I want to measure, that the achieved performance gain is significant or not. Below is my data example:

```
           LA        LB
Task1      2.3       4.1 (mean values of 10 executions)
Task2      5.6       2.3
Task3      10.5      3.4
Task4      15.2      4.6
Task5      11.3      3.1
```

I have the following questions:
1. Which test should I apply to find the significance?
2. Can I apply that test on mean values rather than real 10 execution values?
3. Which parameters (Alpha, P, t) of the test must be presented in table and discussed, as I cannot present/discuss all parameters due to space limitation.

Thank you

Comment: I fear you may be using "significant" in a non-standard way. Let's focus on your actual needs: what are you trying to find out? Whether one laptop is faster than another? If so, you will need to specify what mix of tasks is relevant for the comparison. Statistical testing cannot make that decision for you.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to prove that executing tasks on Laptop 2 reduces the execution time of the tasks (performance is improved). The issue is that the computational time depends on the task type. For instance, in Task1 case, LA takes less time compared to LB. Whereas, for other 4 tasks 2-4, LB takes less time.

Answer (score 1):

It's too early to apply stats here. First you have to come up with a performance model of the tasks and the application to your laptops.

For instance, you might be dealing with parallelizable tasks 2-5 and a sequential execution task 1; and LA could be double core CPU at 3GHz while LB quasd core at 2.2 GHz CPU. Then you'd apply [Amdahl's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law), and estimate its parameters for a given configuration. This would let you forecast the speed of the systems for given tasks.

Another example could be LA is with SSD but slower CPU and LB is with HDD but faster CPU. Task 1 is disk use heavy, while Tasks 2-5 are CPU heavy. I can come up with any number of configurations that would explain the results. You see that statistics will only help you when you have a reasonable understanding of the process, the hardware, the nature of the tasks (parallel, CPU-bound etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Since your sample size is small, I think you can perform a wilcoxon rank test. For example,
to test the laptop performance:

```
> y<-c(2.3,4.1, 5.6, 2.3, 10.5, 3.4, 15.2, 4.6, 11.3, 3.1)
> laptop<-c(1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0)
> wilcox.test(y, laptop)

        Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction

data:  y and laptop
W = 100, p-value = 0.0001442
```

To test the difference among tasks:

```
> task<-c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5)
> wilcox.test(y, task)

        Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction

data:  y and task
W = 76, p-value = 0.05336
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0
```

which suggests there's no differences among task but significant difference between laptops.

Comment: Dear Dadong Zhang,
Thank you for the guidance. I would like to know, why didn't you use two tail t test? Is it applicable? If yes, what would be the exact procedure for this type of data.

Comment: It's not suitable here to use student-t test because you only have ten observations. Use t test if you have more than 30 obs.

Comment: The use of *any* test on this dataset is questionable. In what sense could the results be modeled as iid samples from two populations?

Comment: @DavidZ - why does a small sample mean you can't use a t-test. (I've heard this said often, but never seen it in print.)